# How do I write a pseudocode to calculate the nth term of an arithmetic series with a difference of b and the first term?

Tags: math, pseudocode, flowchart

please don't use formula `Un = a + (n-1)b`, use looping

I tried to figure this out but i cannot find how to create pseudocode looping without formula

Answer (score 0):

Given `a` and `b`, you can loop `n-1` times and add `b` to the result.

In pseudocode:

```
u = a;
Loop n-1 times: // Note that if n=1, n-1 is 0, and the loop won't happen
   u += b
```